# Query to get count of items with a given status within a given timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

An interesting SQL problem has recently come up at work, one which I haven't been able to solve without multiple steps in the past.

Say you have a simple "ItemStatus" table, which exists to keep track of the status of different items. Columns are "itemId", "date status changed", and "status". Example:

```
ItemId      DateStatusChanged    Status
1           09/01/2016             New
1           10/15/2016             Complete
2           10/20/2016             New
2           10/25/2016             Complete
```

An item is assumed to be the same status until it is changed. So item 1 was "New" starting 9/1, and remained "New" until 10/15, when it changed to "Complete". Item 2 was "New" from 10/20 to 10/25.

So say you want to query the table to get a count of how many unique items had a status of "New" anytime within October 2016 (which in this case would be "2"). Is there a single SQL query that can return this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of the common SQL problems related to timelining; yes there is a solution.  A simpler, more efficient query can be written if the records also have termination dates, but of course while that means you're not inferring as much when looking at just one record, it also creates the problems of potentially invalid sequences (e.g. overlapping states or gaps in the timeline).  So...

```
select count(distinct ItemId)
  from ItemStatus is1
 where status = 'New'
   and DateStatusChanged < '2016-11-01' -- syntax may vary
   and not exists
       (select 1 
          from itemstatus is2
         where is2.itemid = is1.itemid
           and is2.status != 'New'
           and is2.datestatuschanged > is1.datestatuschanged
           and is2.datestatuschanged < '2016-10-01')
```

You may have to adjust some `<` vs `<=`, etc., depending on exact desired logic, timestamp granularity, etc.

Comment: Ah, yes, perfect - that's along the lines of what I was thinking in pseudo-SQL but couldn't quite translate. I knew that a "placeholder" variable of some kind would be needed for the datestatuschanged where status='New', as one wants to check for the existence of any non-"New" status change records for the item in question *after* that date but before Oct. 1. Thanks much!

Comment: I think that last line was a typo, though -- running that query as is returns a count of 1. To get a count of 2 (which is correct -- both items were "New" at some point within October 2016), the last line of the query should read "and is2.datestatuschanged < '2016-10-01'".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead` to get the next status change date for each itemid based on ascending order of datestatuschanged. Then check if the next change or the existing changedate is between the given dates and count those items.

```
select count(distinct ItemID) 
from (select i.*
     ,lead(datestatuschanged) over(partition by itemid order by datestatuschanged) as next_change
      from itemstatus i
      ) x
where status = 'New'
and ( (next_change >= '2016-10-01' and next_change <= '2016-10-31')
      or 
      (datestatuschanged >= '2016-10-01' and datestatuschanged <= '2016-10-31')
    )
```

Comment: Good use of window function [`Lead()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) .  Though I think the date logic is overly complex.  Don't you just need to check that the "new" record has a dateStatusChanged <=2016-10-1 and that the next_Change occurred after 2016-10-1?  (perhaps `coalesce(next_change,getDate()) > '2016-10-1`?)  (assuming next_change is a date not date time)

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know about the lead() function before. I'll play around with it. xQbert - the only problem with that is that the "new" record can have a dateStatusChanged after 2016-10-01 (as in the case of ItemId 2). I basically want all items that have a "new" record on or before 10/31, where the item's next non-"new" record occurs after 10/1 (or doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to make each row have a New and Complete date. From there the query is actually fairly simple.

Something like this should point you in the right direction.

```
select count(distinct ItemID) as ItemCount
from 
(
    select ItemID
        , max(case when Status = 'New' then DateStatusChanged end) as NewDate
        , Max(case when Status = 'Complete' then DateStatusChanged end) as CompleteDate
    from YourTable
    group by ItemID
) MyItems
where NewDate >= '2016-10-01'
    and CompleteDate >= '2016-10-01'
    and CompleteDate >= NewDate --just to ensure that is wasn't marked complete before it was marked new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
select ItemId from (
select itemid, status, RowN = row_number() over (partition by itemid order by status) from youritem where MONTH(datestatuschanged) = 10 and year(datestatuschanged) = 2016  ) as SourceTable
pivot(max(status) for RowN in ([1],[2])) p
where [1] = 'Complete' and [2] = 'New'
```

Idea is to transpose both status into columns and compare and select only the required month and year

Comment: That's similar to how I solved it in the past, only I was using server-side code to build a query object on the fly and then go back and query that query object. Thanks for showing an all-SQL solution!

Answer (score 0):

Easily adapted to a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` with a `WHERE Status = 'New'`, the following CTE will give you the status for each item on each day of the month of October:

```
;WITH DATE_CTE ( aDate ) AS (
    SELECT CAST('2016-10-01' AS DATETIME)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, cte.aDate)
      FROM DATE_CTE cte
     WHERE cte.aDate < CAST('2016-10-31' AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT i.itemid, dates.aDate, i.status 
  FROM DATE_CTE dates
        INNER JOIN itemstatus i 
            ON i.DateStatusChanged <= dates.aDate
        LEFT OUTER JOIN itemstatus i2 
            ON i.ItemId = i2.ItemId 
           AND i.DateStatusChanged < i2.DateStatusChanged 
           AND dates.aDate >= i2.DateStatusChanged
 WHERE i2.DateStatusChanged IS NULL
 ORDER BY i.itemid, dates.aDate
```

Proper answer:

```
;WITH DATE_CTE ( aDate ) AS (
    SELECT CAST('2016-10-01' AS DATETIME)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, cte.aDate)
      FROM DATE_CTE cte
     WHERE cte.aDate < CAST('2016-10-31' AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.itemid)
  FROM DATE_CTE dates
        INNER JOIN itemstatus i 
            ON i.DateStatusChanged <= dates.aDate
        LEFT OUTER JOIN itemstatus i2 
            ON i.ItemId = i2.ItemId 
           AND i.DateStatusChanged < i2.DateStatusChanged 
           AND dates.aDate >= i2.DateStatusChanged
 WHERE i.Status = N'New'
   AND i2.DateStatusChanged IS NULL
```